# Google calendar All day event edit functionality in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api

I integrated Google calendar in my `iOS` application with swift programming language , when I try to edit all day event to regular event I got error like this

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=400 "Invalid start
>   time." UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x600000645130:
>   {message:"Invalid start time." errors:[1] code:400},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid start time.}

For all day add event I passed date parameters like

```
    newGoogleEvent.start?.date =  GTLRDateTime.init(forAllDayWith:Date())
```

for edit the all day event to regular event I passed parameters like

```
      newGoogleEvent.start?.dateTime =  GTLRDateTime.init(date: Utilitys.datafomatter(dateString: allEventsValue.starts!)!)
```

Comment: Can you share what your request looks like? Additionally, you can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars) for further reference.

Comment: All day event request :

{location:"" summary:"All day event " sequence:1 start:{date:"2017-10-31"} htmlLink:"" end:{“2017-11-01”} reminders:{} transparency:"opaque" description:""}

Edited all  day event response to regular event :

 {location:"" summary:"All day event " sequence:1 start:{dateTime:2017-10-31T12:00:00Z} htmlLink:"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NWY3YnVxYjhsc3I0cWtzaGM5bWc4OWsxMnMgYmhhZ3lhYmxvc3NvbTlAbQ" end:{dateTime:2017-10-31T13:00:00Z} reminders:{useDefault,overrides} transparency:"opaque" description:""}
Using GTLRCalendarQuery to execute event operations.

Comment: @BhagyaG If possible can you post how you fetching the events data from google calendar?